# dateFormat not working -> TypeError: Invalid date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date

I'm trying to convert 2022-01-17T21:36:04.000Z into January 18th type format. I'm doing with the help of npm package dateFormat.

I'm able to achieve this easily with:

```
const date = dateFormat("2022-01-17T21:36:04.000Z", "mmmm dS");
```

But instead of hardcoding if I pass value like this, it doesn't seem to work.

```
 
const convertDate = (dateformat) => {
  

    const date = dateFormat(`"${dateformat}"`, "mmmm dS");
    console.log(date);
```

I'm getting TypeError: Invalid date.

```
console.log(`"${dateformat}"`)  // is giving me -> "2022-01-17T21:36:04.000Z"
```

Comment: `\`"${dateformat}"\`` -> \`${dateformat}\`

Comment: Or just `dateformat` with no quotes at all.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
const date = dateFormat(`"${dateformat}"`, "mmmm dS");
```

use the variable directly:

```
const date = dateFormat(dateformat, "mmmm dS");
```